# Inserting values with specific date and time format in Oracle

Tags: oracle11g, oracle10g

I tried to insert values into SURVEY.YSG table ( used in the insert query )

```
INSERT INTO SURVEY.YSG(YSG_ID,YSG_MSN_DTM,TAX_ID,TAX_NM,TYPE_CD,USER_ID,
                       FRST_NM,LAST_NM,SHL_TXT,NPR_DT, PHONE_NBR,FAX_NBR,
                       EMAIL_ADRS_TXT,YSG_IMD,MDFD_ID,YSG_VRFCTN_CD,
                       YSG_VRFCTN_DTM,LOG_KEY,PLS_DTM,LOAD_KEY,UPDTD_LOAD_KEY ) 
   VALUES ( '103','2011-08-11 13:34:36.000000','656002075',
           'STG HEALTH SYSTEM','null','OPLINKS4','UNK','UNK','UNK',
           '12/31/8888','UNK','UNK','UNK','X','UNK','Y','8888-12-31 00:00:00.000000',
           0,'2011-07-20 12:00:00.000000',0,0)
```

> Error report:
>   SQL Error: ORA-01843: not a valid month
>   01843. 00000 -  "not a valid month"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Below are the 4 columns created with date and timestamp in `SURVEY.YSG` table.

```
YSG_MSN_DTM - TIMESTAMP(6)

NPR_DT - DATE

YSG_VRFCTN_DTM - TIMESTAMP(6)

PLS_DTM - TIMESTAMP(6)
```

tried with `TO_DATE()` function:

```
TO_DATE('2011-08-11 13:34:36','YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
```

Got output like: `11-AUG-11 01.34.36.000000000 PM.`

Expected Output:

column: `YSG_MSN_DTM` -> `2011-08-11 13:34:36.000000` 
and for column `NPR_DT` ->`12/31/8888` in another column.

is there any other way to achieve this in Oracle?

Any of your help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` columns don't have any intrinsic format. When you display them you supply a format - and if you supply no format the current session's NLS settings are used to provide a default format.

Comment: Agree to that.Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO
      SURVEY.YSG ( YSG_ID,
                YSG_MSN_DTM,
                TAX_ID,
                TAX_NM,
                TYPE_CD,
                USER_ID,
                FRST_NM,
                LAST_NM,
                SHL_TXT,
                NPR_DT,
                PHONE_NBR,
                FAX_NBR,
                EMAIL_ADRS_TXT,
                YSG_IMD,
                MDFD_ID,
                YSG_VRFCTN_CD,
                YSG_VRFCTN_DTM,
                LOG_KEY,
                PLS_DTM,
                LOAD_KEY,
                UPDTD_LOAD_KEY )
VALUES
      ( '103',
        TO_TIMESTAMP ( '2011-08-11 13:34:36.000000',
                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' ),
        '656002075',
        'STG HEALTH SYSTEM',
        'null',
        'OPLINKS4',
        'UNK',
        'UNK',
        'UNK',
        TO_DATE ( '12/31/8888',
                'MM/DD/YYYY' ),
        'UNK',
        'UNK',
        'UNK',
        'X',
        'UNK',
        'Y',
        TO_TIMESTAMP ( '8888-12-31 00:00:00.000000',
                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' ),
        0,
        TO_TIMESTAMP ( '2011-07-20 12:00:00.000000',
                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF' ),
        0,
        0 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!I tried with this option too, OUTPUT : TIMESTAMP field 11-AUG-11 01.34.36.000000000 PM and for DATE field 31-DEC-88. I want exactly the same type to be inserted as how in TERADATA DB. It is migrating from Teradata to Oracle environment.

Comment: Try to alter the session for date value. For example         ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='YYYY.MM.DD HH24:MI:SS';

Comment: I used both NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT and NLS_DATE_FORMAT to achieve the same.Thanks for your help :)